# Finding the minimal polynomial of a matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

> $$ Let \qquad A=
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     3 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 1 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 1 \\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is: $p_A(x)=\det(xI-A)$
>   Now $
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     x & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & x & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & x \\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $- 
>   $
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & x & x^2 \\
>     1 & y & y^2 \\
>     1 & z & z^2 \\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $ = $
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     x-3 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & x-1 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & x-1 \\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $
>   So,  $$\det  \begin{pmatrix}
>     x-3 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & x-1 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & x-1 \\
>     \end{pmatrix}= (x-3)(x-1)^2=p_A(x)$$
>   Since the minimal polynomial must be the divisor of the characteristic polynomial, the minimal polynomial is either $(x-3)(x-1)$ or $(x-3)(x-1)^2$

Until here these are what I know.
I saw a guy on youtube when finding the minimal polynomial did this computation below:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} -\begin{pmatrix}
    3 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} -\begin{pmatrix}
    3 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    -2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$ , so the minimal polynomial of $A$ is:$(x-1)(x-3)$
What is the computation above ? Is it $m_A(x)$ or $m_A(A)$ ?

Comment: Since $(A-I)(A-3I)=0$, you find $(x-1)(x-3)$ to be the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of a diagonalizable matrix has distinct roots and every eigenvalue must be a root.

For the particular case, you can dispense with the theorem above, as it's easy to verify that $(A-I)(A-3I)=0$, but neither $(A-I)^2=0$ nor $A-3I=0$. So the minimal polynomial must be $(x-1)(x-3)$.